# Address Value in Assembly

Tags: assembly, memory-address

I have the following assembly program :

[image: Assembly Program]

**My question is : Why does the Address Value increases by 3h in every process 
and sometimes its only increases by 1h like :**

0010h
0011h
0012h
.
.
.

Comment: Does this architecture have variable-length instructions?  I'm guessing it does, just looking at the "Op-Code" column.

Comment: @Gian all the variables are from type "word" 16bit
but is this has anything to do with the value of the address ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the machine code in this case <sup>(a)</sup> isn't a fixed number of bytes per instruction, it varies depending on the instruction itself. You can see the bytes making up each instruction in the opcode column.

The instruction at `0010` takes three bytes with the `aa` meaning load an immediate byte into a register, the `00` meaning register `r0`, and the `02` giving the immediate byte value to load. This is evident because the same `aa` opcode is used to load up `r1` in the following instruction.

Contrast that with the instruction at `0019` which has the two bytes `d4 20`. The length of the instruction is what controls the address of the following instruction.

Perhaps expanding it out may help your understanding:

```
0010  AA  MAIN:  MVI R0, 2
0011  00
0012  02

0013  AA         MVI R1, -1
0014  10
0015  FF

0016
:
```

An instruction tends to consist of an opcode which controls what is to be done, along with other information giving more fine-grained details (the operands) which may provide such things as immediate data or addressing modes (immediate, memory, indexed, I/O ports, scaled and a whole host of other possibilities). For example, it's evident from your example that `aa` is the load register immediate opcode that works as follows:

```
aa x0 yy    ; rx <- yy
|| |  ||
|| |  ++--> immediate byte to load in to register
|| +------> register to receive byte
++--------> fixed opcode aa
```

Similarly, the `add` instruction at `001e` indicates how to add two registers together:

```
b2 xy       ; rx <- rx + ry
|| ||
|| |+-----> register to add to rx
|| +------> register to receive sum (rx)
++--------> fixed opcode b2
```

A final example of the opcode/operands dichotomy is the jump instruction (actually both them, `jmp` and `jnz`) - it has a controlling opcode with the next two bytes specifying the absolute address to jump to (in little-endian format).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Certainly there are architectures where instructions *are* fixed length such as on certain RISC CPUs where the fixed lengths (and fixed positions of fields within the instruction) enabled the instruction decoding to be much simpler (and therefore, hopefully, much faster).

The particular architecture in your question is, however, not one of those.